# Creating subclasses using Single table Inheritance (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the class User, and subclasses Admin and Student.

Student should have additional dedicated columns. Please let me know how I can do this using STI in Ruby on Rails.

Thanks!

Also, how do I populate the users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, typically you'd have `type` column on the `User` class. Now in your subclasses you'd inherit from the `User` class as such:

```
class User

end

class Admin < User

end

class Student < User

end
```

This way you can take advantage of the Rails STI and still be able to flexibly create methods for your subclasses.

Find more information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

However to keep it a bit organized, you could put the subclasses in a folder under your models, as such

```
#models/users/admin.rb
module Users
  class Admin < User

  end
end

#model/users/student.rb
module Users
  class Student < User

  end
end
```

Now to use your classes, you'd do `Users::Student.find(id)`

**UPDATE**

In response to the comment, I think for the columns that would be specific to the student, you'd be better served by an association, say `Student.has_one :grade` or something of sorts, this way you'd have successfully abstracted your user object to deal with the common User methods. But to create a row for `Student` and `Admin`
You could do `Users::Student.create(params)` or `Users::Admin.create(params)` and Rails knows how to deal with the STI

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how do I columns that are specific to Student (say "grade")? Also, how do I create a row for Student and Admin now?

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible for Student to be a subclass of User, and have a separate column called "grade" as well? Will they share the same table then?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have the column on the users table, but the problem is that your User and Admin also has a redundant grade column, hence the suggestion to have an association table for that. It's called Single Table Inheritance for a reason, emphasis on Single, they would always share the same table

Comment: I think your comment above is incomplete? :)

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. If that resolves your issue, you could accept the answer as well.